# subprocess used in python django does not working when django was host in IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, subprocess

I have using the subprocess package in my django web, when i run local on server or publish using apache, it work without causeing any issue BUT when I host my django web on IIS, this subprocess does not work.

Below is my subprocess code:

```
files = subprocess.check_output("dir /b " + path, shell=True).decode()
p_pcat=subprocess.Popen(['java', '-cp', str(PARSER_JAR), 'parsePCAT.ParsePCAT', str(pcat_file_name)],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

This both function not working when hosting at IIS (version 10.0.14393.0), anyone have idea on this?

Comment: Subprocesses controlled by IIS don't work well with Django. My recommendation is to use Waitress or Apache if you need to run a subprocess. You can find tutorials on how to set that up on YouTube

Answer (score 2):

Try to assign the administrator user to the iis application pool identity by using an advanced setting.

[image]

after assigning administrator user to recycle the application pool and try to access the site again.

if you still face an issue after doing changes enable detailed logging  in iis:

1)select site from iis.

2)click error pages.

[image]

3)click edit feature setting from the action pane.

[image]

access site and check the error.

you could also log error by adding below variable in iis app setting:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019